# Get all links after div object but before next object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This only shows the first link after the group, but I want to show all the links after the group , but not the ones in the next group. Anyone know how its done?

```
$(".group").next("a").show();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="group">Group 1</div>
 <a href="#">Link 1</a>
 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
<div class="group">Group 2</div>
 <a href="#">Link 1</a>
 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
 <a href="#">Link 3</a>
```

Comment: wrap ancchor tags in a div then it will be easy to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(".group").nextAll("a").show();
```

instead of

```
$(".group").next("a").show();
```

To be more specific, you can also use [nextUntil](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)